# how to play video in ios by dragging that videofile to the project in ios?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

hi i want to play video in my project.Actually i know the code to play a video present in `url`. But here i want put these audio files in my project by dragging the video files.I use this code

```
NSString *str=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"monkey" ofType:@"mp4"];
NSURL *url=[NSURL  URLWithString:str];

MPMoviePlayerViewController *movieViewObj=[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieViewObj];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(notiMethod:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayConObj];
```

But this will not run the video file in `ios`.Tell me the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So what doesn't work? What did you find out when you debugged it?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `URLWithString:` but `fileURLWithPath:` for creating an NSURL out of a local resource. Hence, change that second line of your code towards:

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:str];
```